# How to connect two computers on different networks via VPN

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vpn

I recently got a VPN service and I use it for two computers, but I don't fully understand the ins and outs of how it works and how it interfaces with the web.

I currently ssh between these computers over my local network, but I need to work remotely. If it's possible, how can I extend this across two different networks (mobile network or another remote network), ideally using a VPN and using non-3rd-party programs?

My current understanding is:

(via local network)

```
ssh "comp_name"@"local_ip_addr"
```

(via VPN)

```
ssh ????
```

Comment: If you bought commercial VPN service for Internet access... are you sure it even allows connections between clients? I suspect it might be purpose-built to disallow that. (What VPN technologies allow in general is one thing; what commercial VPN services allow is another.)

Comment: If I am parsing things correctly, I believe you need to add a static route of the gateway to tell it which interface it should use for traffic to the other LAN. Given you are passing through other people's network, it is probably not feasible. You will probably have to find another solution, like using Dynamic DNS as a location service, then port forwarding at both endpoints (assuming the endpoints have public IPs).

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you named your VPN service.  However, in general VPN services provide an encrypted tunnel from one endpoint to another.  The first endpoint is one of your computers and the other being the VPN service.  You then connect to the internet from there.  This adds a layer of anonymity to your internet usage.  In addition, they can also allow bypassing physical location restrictions for certain services.  For example, it would allow you to access Netflix from a different country that prohibits access to it.

If this is what your VPN service provides, it does ***not*** provide you the ability to access your computers remotely.  That is not the purpose or design that the commercial service are offering.  Its purpose is to provide anonymity and internet access by connecting to its endpoint.

In order to access your computers, you would need to install a VPN server inside your home network to access it remotely.  This can be done via hardware, or software.  Based on your tag, you are using Ubuntu.  You can install [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/), as it is included in the Ubuntu repository.  However, your requirement of "no 3rd party programs" is confusing as  a Linux distribution, such as Ubuntu, is a collection of 3rd party programs.  You could use purchase a hardware VPN, or perhaps your router supports VPN natively.  You could possibly add VPN functionality by flashing it with new firmware such as [DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com/), or similar replacement firmware, all of which are 3rd party.

If you can get past the "no 3rd party software" requirement, I would recommend [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.us/), as it is easy to set up and use.  It is not a traditional VPN, but remote desktop software, that can create an secure encrypted tunnel to your machine.  It also doesnt require configuring of firewalls, or other advanced techniques to get it working.  It is free for personal use.